# Virtual Button scaled coordinate

Tags: android, objective-c, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am so confused by vuforia virtual buttons sample :
https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/virtual-buttons
there's no any explanation of how the button scaled and how it can get negative value .For example ,how could (90, 850)(290, 925) becomes (-108.68, -53.52)(-75.75, -65.87) ? **why 90 scaled to -108.68 ?**

Comment: What is the parent's scale ?

Comment: 0.16 the original size for the parent image was (1500, 1050) and after scaling (247, 173)

Comment: Did you change the scale of your parent after you put your child

Comment: No, i didn't change anything

Comment: i just wanna understand how can i get scaled image coordinates from the original one! what's used theory ??

Comment: I thought that if you scale a parent, it will have repercussion on your child. I have all the time that problem, that's why i asked you. Can you rm your child and copy the original one ?

Comment: the parent is already scaled, and also the children .. but i don't know how it works! as it's a public sample and i wanna customize it wiz my own children so i need to know how they did these things ??